# How do I set validation on select Tag in my web form?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to set validation on `select` tag in my form so that the user cannot proceed without choosing a location.

Below is the form...

```
<form name="form1">
    Pickup Suburb: 
    <select id="pick" class="pick" name="pick"/><br />
        <option value="none">-- Please select a location --</option>
        <option value = 1>City </option>
        <option value = 2>Airport </option>
        <option value = 3>Abbotsbury </option>
        <option value = 4>Abbotsford </option>
        <option value = 5>Acacia Gardens </option>
        <option value = 6>Agnes Banks </option>
        <option value = 7>Airds </option>
        <option value = 8>Akuna Bay </option>
    </select>

    <br />Rear facing baby seat 
    <select class="rfbs" name="rfbs" style="width:50px">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select><br />

    <br />Booster seat 
    <select class="bs" name="bs" style="width:50px">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <br />    
    <br />Luggage Trailer 
    <select class="lt" name="lt" style="width:50px">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <br /><input class="show-popup" type="submit" value="Get Quote">
</form>
```

I have applied a `JavaScript`popup window to show the results when user fills the form so is it possible to apply validation that shows an error message if the user tries to submit the form without choosing a location.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Because select field has always been chosen value (default first option), you can just check:

```
if($('#pick').val()=='none') {    
  alert('choose some value');
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form element allows a onSubmit tag that will get called if the user tries to submit the form.

You could try something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="checkFormValidity()">
<select id="location" ... >
```

Then in your javascript you can then do something like this:

```
function checkFormValidity(){

  var select = document.getElementById("location");
  if(select.options.selectIndex == 0)
  { 
    return false; 
  }
  return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line I would like to add to make sure that `form` will not be submitted

```
if($('#pick').val()=='none'){
    alert('choose some value');
    return false;  // this is a missing line
}
```

Note: To use `jQuery`, you need to [download](http://jquery.com/download/) it and add it to your web form

**Edit:**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
Pickup Suburb: 
    ....
</select>
<br /><input class="show-popup" type="submit" value="Get Quote">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$( "#form1").submit(function( event ) {
    if($('#pick').val()=='none'){
        event.preventDefault(); //will prevent default form submission
        alert("Please select one of the options provided");
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can check [***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddlestackover/eavAr/) on jsfiddle

Comment: its still not working, if i am sumbitting the form without selecting the location frm options it is showing the popup window and not the alert,error

Comment: Have you added jQuery script tag? and a Have you called function on `Submit`?

Comment: i have already added this file http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js in head of file to support the js. window popup

Comment: I have edited the answer with correction. Check correction for `method='post'` and `id='form1'`